# options for using "identify" command with public api

Tags: api, arcgis-platform

**Disclaimer:** I'm new to GIS

**Goal:** Create a report of how many customers we have in each senate district.

**Progress:** I found [this utility](https://ogi.oa.mo.gov/LEGIS/legislativeDistrict/index.html) from the state of Missouri which allows me to search for an address and it displays the corresponding district.  I did some debugging and found that it looks like it is doing two calls to an `ArcGIS` server (Using Branson, MO as example):

1. `https://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer/findAddressCandidates?SingleLine=branson, mo&f=json&outSR={"wkid":102100,"latestWkid":3857}&outFields=*`
2. `https://ogi.oa.mo.gov/ArcGIS/rest/services/LEGIS/legisDistrict/MapServer/identify?f=json&geometry={"x":-10377036.95984281,"y":4389554.630050001,"spatialReference":{"wkid":102100,"latestWkid":3857}}&tolerance=1&returnGeometry=true&mapExtent={"xmin":-10377151.615385238,"ymin":4389439.974507573,"xmax":-10376922.304300383,"ymax":4389669.285592428,"spatialReference":{"wkid":102100}}&imageDisplay=1599,845,96&geometryType=esriGeometryPoint&sr=102100&layers=visible:1`

The first call returns a list of `candidate` objects like this:

```
{
    "spatialReference": {
        "wkid": 102100,
        "latestWkid": 3857
    },
    "candidates": [
        {
            "address": "Branson, Missouri, United States",
            "location": {
                "x": -10377036.95984281,
                "y": 4389554.630050001
            },
            "score": 100,
            "attributes": {...},
            "extent": {
                "xmin": -10383716.235155277,
                "ymin": 4381233.546051718,
                "xmax": -10370357.896260085,
                "ymax": 4397882.30382274
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The second call returns a list of result objects:

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "layerId": 1,
            "layerName": "Senate District",
            "displayFieldName": "District",
            "value": "29",
            "attributes": {
                "OBJECTID": "29",
                "District": "29",
                "Population": "181191",
                "webLink": "http://www.senate.mo.gov/15info/members/mem29.htm",
                "photoLink": "http://www.senate.mo.gov/15info/graphics/d29-photo.gif",
                "Name": "David Sater",
                "Shape": "Polygon",
                "District_Number": "29",
                "Shape.area": "8040296221.235743",
                "Shape.len": "505379.224253"
            },
            "geometryType": "esriGeometryPolygon",
            "geometry": {}
        }
    ]
}
```

`attributes.district` being the value I want.

As you can see above, the second call sends a parameter called `geometry` which is a combination of `location` and `spatialReference`, as well as `mapExtents` which is a combination of `extent` and `spatialReference`.  It also sends some other things.

The point is, this seems to require a lot of object/string manipulation to do both calls.  The question is, are both calls necessary?  Is there another way to call `/identify`, perhaps directly with latlng which I already have?  I've looked at [the documentation](https://ogi.oa.mo.gov/arcgis/sdk/rest/index.html#//02ss000000m7000000) and I don't see anything, but to be honest I don't even understand what `mapExtent` is or why I need it.  Why would it be different for every point I query?

Comment: Where are your customers stored?  BTW, if you're doing redistricting, it might be easier just to use Esri's [Redistricting Online](http://www.esri.com/software/redistricting).

Comment: My customer list is in a spreadsheet, unfortunately.  We are not redistricting, just running a report

Comment: If you have an ArcGIS online subscription, this method might make more sense.  You'd need to pull data from your spreadsheet and pass it as a featureset for the pointlayer option. https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/analysis/api-reference/aggregate-points.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up just doing the string manipulation.  I'll vote to close this as "too broad" but I wanted to post my full code here in case it helps anyone.

**Excel VBA using [VBA-WEB](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Web) library:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub updateData()
    Dim i As Integer
    On Error Resume Next

    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim tRows As Long
    Dim tCols As Long

    Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Participants")

    For i = 1 To tbl.ListRows.Count
        getAddressData (i)
    Next i


End Sub


Sub getDistrict(rw As Integer, spatialReference As Object, location As Object, extent As Object)
    Dim wkid As String
    wkid = spatialReference("wkid")
    Dim latestWkid As String
    latestWkid = spatialReference("latestWkid")

    Dim x As String
    x = location("x")
    Dim y As String
    y = location("y")

    Dim xmin As String
    xmin = extent("xmin")
    Dim ymin As String
    ymin = extent("ymin")
    Dim xmax As String
    xmax = extent("xmax")
    Dim ymax As String
    ymax = extent("ymax")

    Dim geometry As String
    geometry = "{""x"":" & x & "," & """y"":" & y & ",""spatialReference"":{""wkid"":" & wkid & ",""latestWkid"":" & latestWkid & "}}"

    Dim mapExtent As String
    mapExtent = "{""xmin"":" & xmin & ",""ymin"":" & ymin & ",""xmax"":" & xmax & ",""ymax"":" & ymax & ",""spatialReference"":{""wkid"":" & wkid & ",""latestWkid"":" & latestWkid & "}}"


    Dim arcClient As New WebClient
    arcClient.BaseUrl = "https://ogi.oa.mo.gov/ArcGIS/rest/services/LEGIS/legisDistrict/MapServer/"

    ' Note: querystring params are automatically url-encoded
    Dim Request As New WebRequest
    Request.Resource = "identify"
    Request.AddQuerystringParam "f", "json"
    Request.AddQuerystringParam "geometry", geometry
    Request.AddQuerystringParam "tolerance", "1"
    Request.AddQuerystringParam "returnGeometry", "false"
    Request.AddQuerystringParam "mapExtent", mapExtent
    Request.AddQuerystringParam "imageDisplay", "1599,845,96"
    Request.AddQuerystringParam "geometryType", "esriGeometryPoint"
    Request.AddQuerystringParam "sr", wkid
    Request.AddQuerystringParam "layers", "visible:1"

    ' By default: Request.Method = WebMethod.HttpGet and Request.Format = WebFormat.Json

    Dim Response As WebResponse
    Set Response = arcClient.Execute(Request)

    If Response.StatusCode = WebStatusCode.Ok Then
        Dim district As String
        Dim name As String
        district = Response.Data("results")(1)("attributes")("District")
        name = Response.Data("results")(1)("attributes")("Name")
        Cells(rw, "R").Value = district
        Cells(rw, "S").Value = name
    Else
        MsgBox "Error: " & Response.Content
    End If
End Sub

Sub getAddressData(rw As Integer)
    Dim address As String
    address = Cells(rw, "Q").Value
    Dim arcClient As New WebClient
    arcClient.BaseUrl = "https://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer/"

    ' Note: querystring params are automatically url-encoded
    Dim Request As New WebRequest
    Request.Resource = "findAddressCandidates"
    Request.AddQuerystringParam "SingleLine", address
    Request.AddQuerystringParam "f", "json"
    Request.AddQuerystringParam "outSR", "{""wkid"":102100,""latestWkid"":3857}"
    Request.AddQuerystringParam "outFields", "*"

    ' By default: Request.Method = WebMethod.HttpGet and Request.Format = WebFormat.Json

    Dim Response As WebResponse
    Set Response = arcClient.Execute(Request)

    If Response.StatusCode = WebStatusCode.Ok Then
        Dim spatialReference As Dictionary
        Dim location As Dictionary
        Dim extent As Dictionary
        Set spatialReference = Response.Data("spatialReference")
        Set location = Response.Data("candidates")(1)("location")
        Set extent = Response.Data("candidates")(1)("extent")
        getDistrict rw, spatialReference, location, extent
    Else
        MsgBox "Error: " & Response.Content
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I forgot I'm not on SO and I don't have enough rep to vote for closure :\